# Orphaned Child Objects issues with EF 6.1.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have domain object with following structure

```
   public class Country : Entity
    {
        public Country()
        {
            States=new List<State>();
        }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string CountyCode { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; private set; }


        public State GetStateById(int stateId)
        {
            return States.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == stateId);
        }

        public void DeleteState(int stateId)
        {
            var state = GetStateById(stateId); 
            if(state==null) return;
            States.Remove(state);
        }


    }
```

Here i am removing a state object ( which is the child of a country) using the method DeleteState.

And i have repository (and it is an aggregate root) with following structure

```
public class CountryRepository : Repository<Country>, ICountryRepository
    {
        public CountryRepository(IErpBaseUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
            : base(unitOfWork)
        {
        }

       // Unnecessary codes removed

       public void Modify<TEntity>(TEntity item)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        //this operation also attach item in object state manager
        Entry<TEntity>(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    }
```

**and the unitofwork.commit calling Context.SaveChanges**

Business layer

```
public class CountryAppService : ICountryAppService
    {
        private readonly ICountryRepository _countryRepository;
        public CountryAppService(ICountryRepository countryRepository)
        {
            _countryRepository = countryRepository;

        }

 public CountryDto RemoveState(int stateId, int countryid)
        {
            var country = _countryRepository.FindById(countryid);
            if (country == null || country.Status == false) throw new ApplicationOperationException(Messages.Validation_CountryInInvalidState) { HttpCode = 400 };
            country.DeleteState(stateId);
            _countryRepository.Modify(country);
            _countryRepository.UnitOfWork.Commit();
            return country.ProjectedAs<CountryDto>();

        }


}
```

Here i am deleting  the state object by removing the object from the collection, but EF will generates an error because of the presence of an orphan state, My question is how i can delete the state by removing from the collection. key points to consider

**1.) My domain model have no any clue about EF or its related techniques so it is not good idea to include few Ef related code in Domian layer also in Business layer
2.) I am using Db Context with CodeFirst ,**

What are the best practices available to handle this type of situations

Comment: have you ever resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at [ef cascade on delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#CascadeDelete)
With fluent api you can tell EF that orphans are removed when the principal is deleted.

Having said that, EF will not always allow cascade on delete. Due to complex relationships.

In such cases you `could` put the delete children in you DAL layer logic.
I would do that if from a domain model perspective, delete Main Implies Delete all children
and this service is expected/required.

However the way the data is related is often seen as a domain layer topic.

I put Delete children in business logic that i have in Domain layer personally. 
I see no problem if the Domain layer modelled that and called triggered a child delete.
But I have seen and have no issue with service layer/Business layer that sits above the domain layer orchestrating that.  I just treat these as parts of an overall design. indirectly of course you have linked you domain layer to service layer when the service/business layer responsible for orchestrating related deletes.  The domain integrity lies where ?

Best practice is dictated by how you have defined how you see the domain layer.
That is not an StackOverflow question really. It is very large design topic question.
Perhaps to start some reading off on DDD 
http://domaindrivendesign.org/books/